# libgdx: android build has graphical glitches

Tags: android, opengl-es, libgdx

Currently I'm trying to make replica of pacman with libgdx. I done tile map renderer and got a graphical glitch, but glitch only appears in Android build. In first pic you can see that image is "mirroring", also notice that [Cool Tool](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ds.cpuoverlay&hl=en) (third-party overlay system monitor from Google Play) is mirroring too! So i come here for some help, any ideas?

P.S. English is not my native language, please be patient (but say if there blunders).

[image: http://img43.imageshack.us/img43/6564/screenshot2013031718574.png]

[image: http://img26.imageshack.us/img26/2876/screenshot2013031718575.png]

Comment: I fixed that. Thats was simple: i forget to clean screen before draw and that from where problems come. Would ask in 7 hours (because of reputation lower than 10) if no one do it earlier.

Comment: Good question. +1 for the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forget to clear screen before draw. On PC that was okay for some reason, on Android it gived strange glitches (even whitout any animation / moving on the screen). To clear screen i used:

```
Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0); 
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

Comment: I have the same problem, but this doesn't solve it, as I need the screen NOT to clear on each frame.

Comment: @olivarra1 just clear it one time and it should be fine

Comment: the problem is that I want to keep what was drawn before without having to redraw absolutely everything.

Comment: @olivarra1 just clear it ONCE at initialization, before any draw calls. That's worked well for me.